# Javascript : Array anti-pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, anti-patterns

I'm trying to get myself around the insights of JavaScript, currently learning it.

At arrays, I've been reading that the followng is an anti-pattern :

```
var a = new Array("a", "b", "c");
```

and the the following, is not :

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

I'm often having hard times with understanding [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), because I'm tempted to make analogy with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) altough, I shouldn't! Could you please explain me why is this?

Comment: I think calling a simple array declaration a "pattern" (anti- or not) is getting a bit carried away. But yes, `[]` is best practice.

Comment: The book I'm reading is called JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov, he decided to go with this terminology a lot in his book, and I have done the same. I agree with your opinion, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least three reasons people argue you should use the literal syntax (`[...]`) rather than the array constructor:

1. The symbol `Array` can be shadowed (someone can give it a different meaning in a given scope), the literal cannot.
2. The literal is shorter and, some would argue, clearer.
3. The `Array` constructor has a funny API:

   - If you only give it *one* argument, then

     - If that argument is a whole number, it uses that argument to set `length`. So `new Array(10)` creates an empty array with a `length` of 10.¹
     - If the argument isn't a number, it uses that argument as the only element in the array. So `new Array("10")` creates an array with one element (`"10"`) because `"10"` isn't a number.
     - If the argument is a fractional number, it's an error. So `new Array(1.1)` fails with "invalid array length" or similar.
   - If you give it more than one argument, it creates an array with that many elements (even if the first argument is a whole number). So `new Array(10, 20)` creates an array with two elements (`10` and `20`).

This varying API is defined in [this part](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array) of the spec.

---

¹ *"...an empty array with a `length` of 10"* That may seem like a strange sentence — how can it be empty and have a `length` of 10?! — but that's how JavaScript's "arrays" work. You could say they're *sparse* arrays. Or you could say [they aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) at all. (This is true of the standard `Array`; the new *typed* arrays, `Int32Array` and such, are genuine arrays.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, the book presented the third reason with an example but it was not quite clear to me why would it be considered an "anti-pattern", but now I have understand. Thanks, again.